# VS code auto code import not working React native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

[SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzQws.png)

Help Please

yarn add @types/react --save-dev

yarn add @types/react-native --save-dev

I am getting multiple Imports and not getting all Components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Delete all node_modules and install again by yarn install**